# Sentences/Verbs

Tags: sentence-construction

1. Are both sentences correct, and do they mean the same:

a) "Tears SLIPPED DOWN my face."

b) "Tears OOZED DOWN my face."

2. In case they are both correct, which form is more commonly use?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. What do you know about the words "slipped" and "oozed"? Why do you think they might not be correct? We can write better answers if we understand what you already know. If you [edit] your question to include some of the details explained in the "Details, Please" link above, we should be able to take your question off hold.

Answer (score 1):

Both correct, I don't hear either that often.

Edit: I should probably state the difference for those two in the answer also:

"Tears slipped down my face" - Could imply that it was a very little amount and that they slipped out, almost as if you didn't want to cry.

"Tears oozed down my face" - A constant stream / an abundance of tears. Not a commonly used phrase in my opinion.

The usual for me is:

"Tears rolled down my face" - slower tears dropping down your face

"Tears flowed down my face" - Implying a river of tears / an abundance of-

"Tears ran down my face" - usually much faster tears

"Tears fell from my eyes"

There is so many ways you could say that sentence alone..

However, I believe its just up to preference, there is not a correct one to use besides some of them imply a different speed of the tear drop.

Comment: Also, I would like to state that oozed implies more-so the same as flow, an abundance of tears rather than just a little.